# How to continue to next loop iteration only if I press a certain key in Julia

Tags: for-loop, iteration, julia, pause

I am using Julia in Atom. I have a for loop which prints out information in each iteration. I want Julia to pause the program at the end of each iteration so that it only continues to the next iteration if a certain key is pressed (for instance, say the 'enter' key) in the REPL. How should I do this?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like the function `readline`, e.g. `println("Should I proceed?"); a=readline(); a == "y" ? 1 : 0` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read keyboard inputs at every keystroke in julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888266/how-to-read-keyboard-inputs-at-every-keystroke-in-julia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work (in REPL as well) :

```
for i in 1:3
    # ...
    println("something")
    readline() # wait for enter key press
end
```

Using [`readline()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.readline) captures keystrokes (which you can assign to a variable to actually read them) until you press enter.